# Smooth scrolling in canvas with javascript and kinetic.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scroll, kineticjs

I want to rebuild this page: http://www.zahia.com/#/en/artistes in javascript and canvas using kinetic.js.

Therefore I need the canvas stage to scroll relative to my mouse-position. Now I got just a solution which works a little bit different and makes my kinetic.js crash even with setTimeout or smaller offset steps.

My current code:

```
stage.on('mouseover', function(){
        var pos=stage.getMousePosition();
        var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
        var offset = stage.getOffsetX();

        while(mouseX > 800){
            setTimeout(function(){
                offset += 20;
                stage.setOffsetX(offset);
            },500);

        }
        while(mouseX < 200){
            offset -= 2;
            stage.setOffsetX(offset);
            pos=stage.getMousePosition();
            mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
        }
        //stage.draw();
    });
```

Any ideas how i can make this relative scroll work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem**

Keep in mind that mouseover is being fired 10-30 times per second.

Therefore your code is adding 10-30 new setTimeout callbacks each second.

This quickly cascades into a crash.

**One solution**

Listen for mousemoves on the stage.

Offset a layer containing your pink panels by more than the mousemove distance to create a parallax effect.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9bqrC/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.0.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container1{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container1',
        width: 400,
        height: 200
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    // listen for mousemoves on container1
    // create a "parallax" movement of layer by
    // moving the layer more than the mousemove
    $(stage.getContent()).on('mousemove', function (event) {
        var pos=stage.getMousePosition();
        var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
        var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
        layer.setX(-mouseX/.5);
        layer.draw();
    });

    // create 12 panels (0-11)
    for(var i=0;i<12;i++){
        addPanel(i*50,"blue"+i);
    }
    layer.draw();


    function addPanel(x,id){

        var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
            id:"blue"+id,
            x: x,
            y: 0,
            width: 50,
            height: 200,
            fill: 'pink',
            stroke: 'lightgray',
            strokeWidth: 3
        });
        rect.number=i;
        rect.on("click",function(){
            $("#results").text("You clicked panel#"+rect.number);
        });
        layer.add(rect);

        var text= new Kinetic.Text({
            x:i*50+(i<10?20:10),
            y:0,
            fontSize:30,
            text:i,
            fill:"white"
        });
        layer.add(text);

    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Drag the mouse to view panels in parallax</h3>
    <h3>Click on a panel to trigger its own click event</h3>
    <p id="results">Results</p>
    <div id="container1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for you fast answer, it worked for me. I just replaced the layer.draw() in the mousemove event with layer.batchDraw() in order to prevent any crash [batchDraw() on html5canvastutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-batch-draw/)